# Management Studio 2012 opens VS2010 by default, need VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssms, file-association, ssms-2012

I'm not sure how to change this but I've got an installation of VS2010 and VS2012 on my machine.  We just upgraded to SSMS 2012, and while my file associations for everything code-related point to VS2012, SSMS 2012 opens VS2010.  What gives?

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see the registry key it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS 2012 still uses the Visual Studio 2010 Shell, so it will be running as a VS2010 application.